# No sound on any bluetooth devices

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth

For reasons unknown, I cannot get sound to work on any Bluetooth device (have tried several headsets and speakers). It always comes out of my main speaker even if I select another output audio source.

Tried restarting my MacBook Pro 2015.

Tried `sudo killall coreaudiod`

What's stranger, is that while none of my Bluetooth speakers or headsets can receive the sound, all of my Bluetooth headsets (in particular) will not only unpair but vanish from my Bluetooth menu after I try them. I have to turn them off and back on to get them to show. During the brief period in which the headsets are on, YouTube will lock up and refuse to play until the device vanishes again.

I kept cycling thru my three headsets over and over trying different sources for audio and suddenly my Logitech H800 started getting shitty tin can audio. I tried another and it got intermittent tin can audio. I restarted the different audio sources several times, reconnected each headset, in turn, several times, and eventually, my audio and connection stability returned to all Bluetooth devices.

This isn't the first time something like this has happened with my Bluetooth audio devices on my Mac and resolving it feels like some sort of voodoo rain dance.

WTH really happened here and how do I fix this *efficiently* when it happens again?